# Open-source SSH terminal client for Windows with tabs, private key auth + more

Tags: windows, open-source, ssh

Moving here a [question locked on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/191140/best-ssh-program-for-windows/191142), with some refinements:

- since nothing assures you that closed-source terminal emulators don't phone home with your login details or private keys, I'm looking for an *open-source* SSH client
- tabbed sessions are a must - PuTTY doesn't have them
- built-in file transfer from the remote server to my local machine (ZMODEM or SFTP). Use case: I want to transfer a particular remote file to my Windows as quickly as possible. SecureCRT, XShell, ZOC support ZMODEM, and I can do `sz myfile`. This [disqualifies PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/zmodem.html) because I'm not going to type the full `pscp` command every time I need to fetch a file.

Wikipedia has a [comparison of SSH clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients#Features). Other desired features:

- configurable keyboard shortcuts
- configurable colors, or at least a light theme

The best candidate I found so far is [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) ([sources](http://download.mobatek.net/sources/) - though it's [not clear](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1543/open-source-ssh-terminal-client-for-windows-with-tabs-private-key-auth-more/1544?noredirect=1#comment3014_1543) just how open sourced it is), which is ridiculously good (X11 forwarding to export the remote display from the server onto your Windows machine!) but really odd in a few respects:

- there's almost no community around it. No GitHub/SourceForge, no forum, no issue tracking
- it's bloated with all sorts of pointless tools, like a text-mode lobotomized Wireshark to capture network traffic, a calculator (yes, the one that comes with Windows is not good), a text-mode list of hardware devices in Windows (?!), a directories diff tool (are they seriously trying to come up with something better than, say, BeyondCompare?) or Cygwin and a bunch of other commands to soup up the Windows terminal

Disqualified:

- [mRemoteNG](http://mremoteng.org) - open source, but no private key authentication support. Seems to simply embed PuTTY.

Comment: What does “tabbed sessions” mean? If you want to have multiple tabs, why not use a generic tabbing utility plus PuTTY?

Comment: @Gilles: because I don't want to use a hack of that sort, and any serious terminal client supports tabbed sessions, with all that entails ([multi-machine command execution](http://serverfault.com/questions/2746/how-do-i-launch-terminal-commands-into-multiple-tabs?rq=1) for instance, or session profiles that can be applied to multiple sessions).

Comment: “Any serious terminal client supports tabbed sessions”: uh, no, that's patently false. If you want multi-machine command execution, that's a separate feature that you need to mention. “Session profiles that can be applied to multiple sessions” sounds like a tautology.

Comment: I'm sorry you got riled up by my tone. ZOC has session profile, *so that* the same profile can be applied to multiple sessions. And I don't actually care for multi-machine command execution. It's just that a terminal client that's built with multi-session support in mind can be improved to handle features like that, while a single-session one like PuTTY will require much more work.

Comment: MobaXterm is on the dead-zone between open source (most of the things in it) and closed source (I believe the wrapper that does most of the cool stuff isn't FOSS), which probably explains the lack of community. The 'odd' features can be removed/customized with the paid version I suspect

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I've linked to your comment. They do mention removing the games features, but nothing about the other stuff.

Comment: There's a Google Chrome [SSH plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) also made, used and open sourced by Google. Does not have all the features you asked for though but its really easy to use as it runs as a browser tab.

Comment: Terminal programs have tabbing, ssh is not a terminal program, it is a shell proxy ( it stands in for a shell on the local end ) so just get a terminal program, and run all your shells in it. That is what the big boys (Unix/Linux users) do.

Comment: @user1066946: interesting; however Chrome crashes for me on a constant basis because I use a lot of tabs.

Comment: @richard: thank you for the condescending answer. I was asking for a Windows program, not a Unix/Linux one.

Comment: I did not tell you to get a Unix program, I said that separating terminal emulation and other functionality (ssh) is not a hack. It is good practice.

Answer (score 21):

As you've already mentioned PuTTY, I may recommend you one thing I'm using at work: **[MTPuTTY](http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/)**. It's a native Windows wrapper around *PuTTY*, which basically adds the "tabbed" feature you're after. It integrates *PuTTY*, so you have all your stored sessions available. You can attach already running single-windowed *PuTTY* sessions, or detach a tab to become such. Another Plus is: it is available as portable app, so no installation required.

But while *MTPuTTY* comes free-of-charge, it's unfortunately not open-source. On the other hand, it's *PuTTY* dealing with the sessions, and *MTPuTTY* just caters the "window collection and organization", so this might still be fitting for you.

[image: MTPuTTY]
<sup>*MTPuTTY* with multiple tabs open, one even with split-view (click image for larger variant)</sup>

---

If open-source is a strong requirement for you, also take a look at [superputty](https://github.com/jimradford/superputty), which offers a similar feature-set as *MTPuTTY* does (I've used this before switching to *MTPuTTY*, as I couldn't get it working with the portable *PuTTY* version). It also supports *KiTTY*, but a minor draw-back might be its dependency on .NET 2.0 or higher.

[image: superputty with multiple tabs open] [image: superputty file transfer]
<sup>*superputty:* multiple open tabs / file transfer (click images for larger variants)</sup>

---

As pointed out in the comments, you might wish to use this in conjunction with [KITTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) instead of *PuTTY*. *KITTY* is a *PuTTY* fork, and offers a.o. experimental ZModem-Support.

As for your "configurable colors": That again can be done with the *PuTTY/KITTY* settings. On my setup, I use e.g. red background to identify production servers (as "red" signifies "danger", so I take extra care when typing in those tabs ;)) With *KiTTY*, you can even use background images.

I have not (yet) used *KiTTY* myself, but at least one colleague of mine swears on it (he also used *PuTTY* before).

Comment: Interesting find. I've added another must-have feature, quick file transfer. ZMODEM would be easiest - does MTPuTTY support it?

Comment: As I wrote: *MTPuTTY* is just a wrapper around *PuTTY*, and basically does nothing but "organize" your *PuTTY* windows. All session-handling is done by *PuTTY* (alternatively [KITTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), I've heard, so you might want to give that one a look, too). So your "protocols" must be supported by the latter :)

Comment: KITTY is interesting, but another weirdo (just like MobaXTerm :) when it comes to having a [forum](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?action=forum&zone=en) ("it's actually closed"), sane source code hosting (haven't these French SSH client developers heard of GitHub?), or a web page that seems cobbled together after Y2K.

Comment: At least the [portable variant](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/kitty-portable) does have a [page on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Source/KiTTY/). But as I wrote, I've never used KiTTY, so I didn't check more closely on it.

Comment: Cool! I have been using KiTTY, like, forever now, so **superputty** looks like a great addition to my burgeoning toolbox. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: My very first interaction with SuperPuTTY, within 1 minute of installing it, was a [big fat exception message](http://i.snag.gy/IA4Rv.jpg).

Comment: SuperPuTTY is unusable. I've imported a PuTTY session that works perfectly. I can connect to it using "Connect external", but not using "Connect".

Comment: Must be something specific with your setup. I used it for about 2 years without trouble, simply double-clicked the imported sessions to open them. I'm no longer using it, as I switched to MTPuTTY, so I cannot check anymore.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Message from future: I personally actively ignore github because it was bought by the microsoft. I use https://gitlab.com . But probably there are putty mirrors also on the github.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica which is why I moved most of my projects from GH to Codeberg. GitLab is running on Google, so I didn't want to migrate there. But may I ask what you refer to with *putty* mirrors on Github? Neither was Github mentioned here, nor putty recommended.

Comment: wow. I was using mtputty for years now. I never knew it supported these other features too.