# Good-looking PuTTY alternative

Tags: windows, desktop-client, ssh

I need a better SSH client than Putty for Windows.

Major reason being that PUTTY is ugly, the color schemes are really hard to read and annoying. I would prefer something that has a more modern look.

What do you use and would recommend ?

Comment: What do you mean by “better ssh client than putty”? The only requirement you give is to support less “ugly” color schemes (which is vague: I don't find PuTTY ugly), but since PuTTY itself meets this requirement (you can change the colors), that's not really useful.

Comment: Please take a moment to read our [recommendations on asking questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and on [asking for alternatives](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software).

Comment: Check out [cmder](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/) which is a better terminal emulator for Windows. It includes msysgit which is an UNIX toolchain that includes the "ssh" command, in addition to standard cp/rm/mv/etc.

Comment: @Gilles Do you really think better UI means being able to change colors? I don't think anyone here is having any issues comprehending the question so I think I'll leave it as is.

Comment: How do I know what better “UI means”? Only you can know what you mean by it. (Is that what you want? The question asks for “good-looking”, which overlaps but does not cover the same things.)

Comment: Can you please stop spamming you are making no sense, I think everyone seems to understand my question perfectly well. I know you want to link your question and your answer here but please find some other place.

Comment: @sublime the "alleged spammer" is moderator here (see the diamond at the end of his name?), so be careful :) Apart from that, have you checked the link Gilles posted? I was thinking to vote to reopen your question as I think I *halfway* (not *perfectly*, as you've put it) get what you're looking for – but I cannot do so as it doesn't meet this site's standards, as outlined in the posts Gilles linked. So please [edit] your post to match up, it's a good question in its core apart from that (as the answers show).

Comment: ^yes I completely understand that he's a moderator, but I've spent enough time on this question.

Comment: Also see: [Open-source SSH terminal client for Windows with tabs, private key auth + more](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1543/185)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), which is a terminal program like PuTTY but with (in my opinion, at least) a cleaner design and a more modern look.

It was recommended to me quite some time ago as a replacement for PuTTY.

Even though it comes in a free version or a full version (which is a subscription), I've used the free version for a very long time and have never noticed any limitations as a result.

Comment: Looks like being worth a look: has a portable version available, and seems to support SSH keys for authentication. Little drawbacks to mention: the limits of the free version (though they sound reasonable and should not affect the average user), and the price for the full version (~EUR 60) – where the term "subscription" somehow suggests repeated payment.

Comment: Okay I've been using this for last 4 days now and it's really awesome. Specially the folder structure that I can navigate alongside my ssh terminal. Multitabs work great and has a very chrome like UI (looks really good). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You've almost convinced me as well: this not only substitutes for "putty + MPutty", but almost for WinSCP as well (if it had folder bookmarks in the SFTP browser that is – or did I just miss those?). Just those annoying penguin screensaver is spoiling it. Any way to turn that off?

Comment: @Izzy I've never done it, but there must be an option somewhere.

Comment: Yupp. Penguin-off-option available for USD 69 – it is "intended to be fun" (and not "intended to be turned off"). Didn't find out for the folder bookmarks, though.

Answer (score 5):

Color schemes in PuTTY can be changed. [4bit Terminal Color Scheme Designer](http://ciembor.github.io/4bit/#) is a great web application to generate PuTTY color schemes.

Answer (score 3):

Another ssh client is [Terminals](https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals). I have not used it because PuTTY works fine for me, but after reading its [feature page](https://github.com/Terminals-Origin/Terminals/blob/master/Docs/Features-and-Screen-shots.md), I think it might fit your requirements:

Here are some of these features:

- Multi tab interface
- Resizable terminal window
- Attached and dettached Window
- Customizable toolbars
- Toolbar for computer control panel applets
- Terminal fonts and colors
- Custom connection icon
- Organize connections by Tags (Groups)
- Organize Groups in Tree like in any other Explorer

Comment: Looks pretty good from the screenshots. What I couldn't figure: does it support SSH keys for authentication? Is there a portable version?

Comment: @Izzy Portable version is available under `other available downloads` on the [downloads page](http://terminals.codeplex.com/releases/view/121477). I don't see SSH Keys in the configuration, but I've only fiddled with it for a little bit

Comment: Thanks for the details! Portable variant is very good to have (especially when working on computers you have no admin account on). But without support for SSH keys, it unfortunately doesn't make much sense *for me*. If you figure that definitely, maybe you want to integrate both details with your answer (whether it supports SSH keys, and the pointer to the portable version)? Meanwhile a "heads-up" (+1) for the detailed answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend OpenSSH in Cygwin.

It's for security reasons rather than aesthetics; PuTTY doesn't support elliptic-curve keys, there's no official HTTPS mirror, and it's quite rarely developed.

Cygwin comes with the `mintty` terminal which shares some lineage with PuTTY's terminal emulator, but i find it's more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I use PuTTY Connection Manager. While not a replacement for PuTTY, it offers a good interface with tabbed sessions and several themes.

It is an old software, but I still use it regularly since I haven't found a better alternative. Its most prominent features are:

- Multiple tabbed sessions
- A connection manager side panel
- Configurable hotkeys
- Customizable themes (System, Visual Studio, and Office 2007 themes)

[image: PuTTY Connection Manager Options]

The [project homepage](http://puttycm.free.fr) is no longer online, but [here is a download link](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_NLCn3T52-0MjVkNDA1MmYtYjZhNi00NDQwLTg1YmUtNGNiMjUwZWFkYjQ5&export=download&hl=en_US) that I found [here](http://www.technlg.net/windows/download-putty-and-connection-manager/)

Comment: FWIW, the internet archive has a dump of the project home page at https://web.archive.org/web/20111024211200/http://puttycm.free.fr:80/cms/