# SSH client for Windows with tabbed terminal console

Tags: windows, ssh

What is a simple django-admin startproject mysite?

I am using Bitvise currently and am very happy with it except that I can't create tabbed terminal windows. When I need to have many terminal windows on my desktop, I become less efficient.

Other things I like in an SSH client are:

- Simple to get started with (as I felt Bitvise was)
- Possible to open SFTP window
- Nice if it can save my SSH passphrase so I don't have to enter it every time

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Have you seen [Open-source SSH terminal client for Windows with tabs, private key auth + more](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1543/185)?

Comment: That looks pretty perfect, thanks :-)

Comment: Yupp, it does. But my answer below looks even better to you, I bet :)

Comment: @Izzy Would it be best to move your great answer to the similar question or leave it attached to this one?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I cannot move answers. A mod can merge questions, though – in case this one gets closed as duplicate, for example.

Comment: @Izzy Sounds good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal favorite in this context is **[MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)** – which might go a little beyond what you've asked for. It comes with a built-in [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin), so you can even run Linux commands on your local system. And of course supports tabs (which was why I first checked it out), so you can have multiple sessions in a single window. It even ships with an X Server, so you can have graphical output from your *nix machines on your Windows client:

[image: MobaXterm] [image: MobaXterm]
<sup>*MobaXterm* (source: [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This just scratches on the surface. To find out more, see [its feature list](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/features.html). I'm not a Windows fan – but when forced to use it (e.g. at the place of a customer), I'd always take this one with me. Used it long term at my last customer's place: fast, efficient, reliable. The only little annoyance is the "ad link" in Moba's status bar (hit it far too often accidentially, which then always opened my browser), and the "penguin screenserver" – but those can be disabled if you "go pro" for ~USD 50. Not having a Windows machine, I didn't buy – the free version always was sufficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SuperPuTTY](http://jimradford.github.io/superputty/):

- free
- open source
- tabbed SSH sessions
- can save layout
- no SFTP

[image]